# Installing nextcloud (helm) on linode k8s (v1.19) cluster with nginx-ingress tls/ssl encryption (let's encrypt) dosen't work as expected

Tags: kubernetes-helm, lets-encrypt, nginx-ingress, linode, nextcloud

I tried to install nextcloud on a Linode k8s managed cluster with helm. The installation process was no problem. Everything worked fine. My nextcloud instance is tls encrypted, but when I try to log in, nothing happens. In the console of the browser I only get the information:

```
Refused to send form data to 'http://cloud.my-domain.io/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'".
```

I figured out, that this has probably to do with the fact that nextcloud has a problem with the reverse proxy of my k8s Nginx ingress. I tried out to solve the problem by adding 'overwriteprotocol' => 'https' to my config.php. Then the error message disappears, but I didn't get forward to the account page, I still see only the login page.

I also tried out to use the Nginx ingress of the nextcloud helm chart itself. But that doesn't work at all. When I try to access nextcloud within the browser I only get the information, that the instance is unsafe. No login page, no nextcloud page at all. Just the blank browser page.

In the end, I tried to use nextcloud without any tls, and that works quite fine. But of course, that's not what I want. I wanna have a secure connection to nextcloud.

I have no ideas what else I can do. What I'm doing wrong? I really hope that someone can help me to solve the problem. Thank's for your help!

That's my helm values.yaml:

```
## Official nextcloud image version
## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/nextcloud/tags/
##
image:
  repository: nextcloud
  tag: 19.0.3-apache
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # pullSecrets:
  #   - myRegistrKeySecretName

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

# Number of replicas to be deployed
replicaCount: 1

## Allowing use of ingress controllers
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/
##
ingress:
  enabled: false
  # metadata:
    # annotations:
    #   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    #   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    #   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 4G
    #   kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    #   certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    #   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |-
    #     server_tokens off;
    #     proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

    #     rewrite ^/.well-known/webfinger /public.php?service=webfinger last;
    #     rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
    #     rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json;
    #     location = /.well-known/carddav {
    #       return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
    #     }
    #     location = /.well-known/caldav {
    #       return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
    #     }
    #     location = /robots.txt {
    #       allow all;
    #       log_not_found off;
    #       access_log off;
    #     }
    #     location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
    #       deny all;
    #     }
    #     location ~ ^/(?:autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
    #       deny all;
    #     }
    #   tls:
    #     - secretName: wa-stack-nextcloud-tls
    #       hosts:
    #         - cloud.my-domain.io
    # labels: {}

# Allow configuration of lifecycle hooks
# ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/
lifecycle: {}
  # postStartCommand: []
  # preStopCommand: []

nextcloud:
  host: cloud.my-domain.io
  # username: admin
  # password: changeme
  # Use an existing secret
  existingSecret:
    enabled: true
    secretName: nextcloud-secret
    # for initiator
    usernameKey: username
    passwordKey: password
    # secretName: nameofsecret
    # usernameKey: username
    # passwordKey: password
    # smtpUsernameKey: smtp_username
    # smtpPasswordKey: smtp_password
  update: 0
  datadir: /var/www/html/data
  tableprefix: wa
  persistence:
    subPath:
  mail:
    enabled: false
    fromAddress: user
    domain: domain.com
    smtp:
      host: domain.com
      secure: ssl
      port: 465
      authtype: LOGIN
      name: user
      password: pass
  # PHP Configuration files
  # Will be injected in /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d for apache image and in /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d when nginx.enabled: true
  phpConfigs: {}
  # Default config files
  # IMPORTANT: Will be used only if you put extra configs, otherwise default will come from nextcloud itself
  # Default confgurations can be found here: https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/tree/master/16.0/apache/config
  defaultConfigs:
    # To protect /var/www/html/config
    .htaccess: true
    # Redis default configuration
    redis.config.php: true
    # Apache configuration for rewrite urls
    apache-pretty-urls.config.php: true
    # Define APCu as local cache
    apcu.config.php: true
    # Apps directory configs
    apps.config.php: true
    # Used for auto configure database
    autoconfig.php: true
    # SMTP default configuration
    smtp.config.php: true
  # Extra config files created in /var/www/html/config/
  # ref: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html#multiple-config-php-file
  configs: {}

  # For example, to use S3 as primary storage
  # ref: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/13/admin_manual/configuration_files/primary_storage.html#simple-storage-service-s3
  #
  #  configs:
  #    s3.config.php: |-
  #      <?php
  #      $CONFIG = array (
  #        'objectstore' => array(
  #          'class' => '\\OC\\Files\\ObjectStore\\S3',
  #          'arguments' => array(
  #            'bucket'     => 'my-bucket',
  #            'autocreate' => true,
  #            'key'        => 'xxx',
  #            'secret'     => 'xxx',
  #            'region'     => 'us-east-1',
  #            'use_ssl'    => true
  #          )
  #        )
  #      );

  ## Strategy used to replace old pods
  ## IMPORTANT: use with care, it is suggested to leave as that for upgrade purposes
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
    # type: RollingUpdate
    # rollingUpdate:
    #   maxSurge: 1
    #   maxUnavailable: 0

  ##
  ## Extra environment variables
  extraEnv:
  #  - name: SOME_SECRET_ENV
  #    valueFrom:
  #      secretKeyRef:
  #        name: nextcloud
  #        key: secret_key

  # Extra mounts for the pods. Example shown is for connecting a legacy NFS volume
  # to NextCloud pods in Kubernetes. This can then be configured in External Storage
  extraVolumes:
  #  - name: nfs
  #    nfs:
  #      server: "10.0.0.1"
  #      path: "/nextcloud_data"
  #      readOnly: false
  extraVolumeMounts:
  #  - name: nfs
  #    mountPath: "/legacy_data"

nginx:
  ## You need to set an fpm version of the image for nextcloud if you want to use nginx!
  enabled: false
  image:
    repository: nginx
    tag: alpine
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  config:
    # This generates the default nginx config as per the nextcloud documentation
    default: true
    # custom: |-
    #     worker_processes  1;..

  resources: {}

internalDatabase:
  enabled: false
  name: nextcloud

##
## External database configuration
##
externalDatabase:
  enabled: true

  ## Supported database engines: mysql or postgresql
  type: mysql

  ## Database host
  host: maria-db-mariadb-primary

  ## Database user
  # user: wa-cloud

  # Database password
  # password:

  ## Database name
  database: wa-cloud

  ## Use a existing secret
  existingSecret:
    enabled: true
    secretName: mariadb-secret
    usernameKey: db-username
    passwordKey: mariadb-password

##
## MariaDB chart configuration
##
mariadb:
  ## Whether to deploy a mariadb server to satisfy the applications database requirements. To use an external database set this to false and configure the externalDatabase parameters
  enabled: false

  db:
    name: nextcloud
    user: nextcloud
    password: changeme

  replication:
    enabled: false

  ## Enable persistence using Persistent Volume Claims
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/
  ##
  master:
    persistence:
      enabled: false
      # storageClass: ""
      accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
      size: 8Gi

postgresql:
  enabled: false
  global:
    postgresql:
      postgresqlUsername: nextcloud
      postgresqlPassword: changeme
      postgresqlDatabase: nextcloud
  persistence:
    enabled: false
    # storageClass: ""

redis:
  enabled: true
  usePassword: false
  password: ''

## Cronjob to execute Nextcloud background tasks
## ref: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/background_jobs_configuration.html#webcron
##
cronjob:
  enabled: true
  # Nexcloud image is used as default but only curl is needed
  image: {}
    # repository: nextcloud
    # tag: 16.0.3-apache
    # pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    # pullSecrets:
    #   - myRegistrKeySecretName
  # Every 5 minutes
  # Note: Setting this to any any other value than 5 minutes might
  #  cause issues with how nextcloud background jobs are executed
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  annotations: {}
  # Set curl's insecure option if you use e.g. self-signed certificates
  curlInsecure: false
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  # If not set, nextcloud deployment one will be set
  # resources:
    # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
    # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
    # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
    # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
    # limits:
    #  cpu: 100m
    #  memory: 128Mi
    # requests:
    #  cpu: 100m
    #  memory: 128Mi

  # If not set, nextcloud deployment one will be set
  # nodeSelector: {}

  # If not set, nextcloud deployment one will be set
  # tolerations: []

  # If not set, nextcloud deployment one will be set
  # affinity: {}

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 8080
  loadBalancerIP: nil
  nodePort: nil

## Enable persistence using Persistent Volume Claims
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/
##
persistence:
  # Nextcloud Data (/var/www/html)
  enabled: true
  annotations: {}
  ## nextcloud data Persistent Volume Storage Class
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  storageClass: "linode-block-storage"

  ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
  ## Requires persistence.enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  # existingClaim:

  accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  size: 20Gi

resources: {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #  cpu: 100m
  #  memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #  cpu: 100m
  #  memory: 128Mi

## Liveness and readiness probe values
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes
##
livenessProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 3
  successThreshold: 1
readinessProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 3
  successThreshold: 1
startupProbe:
  enabled: false
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 30
  successThreshold: 1


## Enable pod autoscaling using HorizontalPodAutoscaler
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/
##
hpa:
  enabled: false
  cputhreshold: 60
  minPods: 1
  maxPods: 10

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}


## Prometheus Exporter / Metrics
##
metrics:
  enabled: false

  replicaCount: 1
  # The metrics exporter needs to know how you serve Nextcloud either http or https
  https: true
  timeout: 5s

  image:
    repository: xperimental/nextcloud-exporter
    tag: v0.3.0
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  ## Metrics exporter resource requests and limits
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  ##
  # resources: {}

  ## Metrics exporter pod Annotation and Labels
  # podAnnotations: {}

  # podLabels: {}

  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    ## Use serviceLoadBalancerIP to request a specific static IP,
    ## otherwise leave blank
    # loadBalancerIP:
    annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
      prometheus.io/port: "9205"
    labels: {}
```

And that's my ingress rule:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 4G
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |-
        server_tokens off;
        proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

        rewrite ^/.well-known/webfinger /public.php?service=webfinger last;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json;
        location = /.well-known/carddav {
          return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
        }
        location = /.well-known/caldav {
          return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
          allow all;
          log_not_found off;
          access_log off;
        }
        location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
          deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/(?:autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
          deny all;
        }
  name: wa-stack-cloud-ingress-nginx
  namespace: business
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - cloud.my-domain.io
    secretName: wa-cloud-tls
  rules:
    - host: cloud.my-domain.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nextcloud
                port:
                  number: 8080
```